# Jni jintArray params error

Tags: java, android, arrays, java-native-interface

java:

public int[] native getArray(int[] a);

---

c:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL 

 net_tq5_ArrayTest_getArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray arr) {
return arr;
}
```

---

java:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b = getArray(a);
for(int i=0; i<a.lenght; i++){
   Log.i("ArrayTest: ", "" + b[i]);
}
```

---

The result will be:

```
 ArrayTest: 0
 ArrayTest: 0
 ArrayTest: 0
 ...
```

---

Why ?
Help!

Answer (score 0):

Your c header for function is incorrect. Now it returns jint instead of jintArray. Try to regenerate the header and rebuild the library.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misspelling, it should be jintArray;